# How to use the OrientDB ETL tool to import the entire database data?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I hope that once the import all data, Seemingly in extractor, JDBC query attributes can be only a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ETL tool allows you to import data from your RDBMS to OrientDB via a query that returns all of the table fields and converts them into a class.
To migrate the data you have to create N json file containing the instructions to import individual tables with their relationships.
A simple example of these two json, show how to import two tables, Table-A and Table-B with the relation B <- A.

Create class from TABLE-A

```
{
  "config": {
    "log": "debug"
  },
  "extractor" : {
    "jdbc": { "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
              "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqldb",
              "userName": "root",
              "userPassword": "",
              "query": "select * from TableA" }
  },
  "transformers" : [
   { "vertex": { "class": "TableA"} }
  ],
  "loader" : {
    "orientdb": {
      "dbURL": "plocal:/temp/databases/orientdb",
      "dbAutoCreate": true
    }
  }
}
```

Create class from TABLE-B and link table-b with table-a

```
{
  "config": {
    "log": "debug"
  },
  "extractor" : {
    "jdbc": { "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
              "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqldb",
              "userName": "root",
              "userPassword": "",
              "query": "select * from TableB" }
  },
 "transformers" : [
   { "vertex": { "class": "TableB"} },
           { "edge": { "class": "associate", "direction" : "in",
                        "joinFieldName": "idTableB",
                        "lookup":"TableA.idTableA"
              }
        }
  ], 
  "loader" : {
    "orientdb": {
      "dbURL": "plocal:/temp/databases/orientdb",
      "dbAutoCreate": true
    }
  }
}
```

I hope will be of help.